# How does one get the name of the arguments of a function passed to a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am leaning about promises by building a pedestrian version to understand what is going on, suffice it to say I am stuck at a point where one has to check if the `executor` function has been passed to the `constructor` which has a `resolve` and `reject` as arguments.

This is from the test.

```
it('gets called with two different functions (funception!), resolve and reject', function() {
      var promise = new $Promise(executor); // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      var argsPassedIntoExecutor = executor.calls.argsFor(0);

      expect(argsPassedIntoExecutor.length).toBe(2);
      var resolve = argsPassedIntoExecutor[0];
      var reject = argsPassedIntoExecutor[1];

      expect(typeof resolve).toBe('function');
      expect(typeof reject).toBe('function');
      expect(resolve).not.toBe(reject);
    });
```

What I have thus far:

```
function $Promise(fnc) {
  if (typeof arguments[0] !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('Sorry argument passed to $Promise should an executor function');
  }

  function ArgumentsToArray(args) {
    return [].slice.apply(args);
  }

  console.log(ArgumentsToArray.apply(fnc));

  this._state = 'pending';
  this._value = null;
  this._internalResolve = function(data) {
    if (this._state !== 'pending') return;
    this._value = data;
    this._state = 'fulfilled';
  };
  this._internalReject = function(data) {
    if (this._state !== 'pending') return;
    this._value = data;
    this._state = 'rejected';
  };

  return fnc();
}
```

This is what I tried (excerpt from above) but to no avail:

```
function ArgumentsToArray(args) {
    return [].slice.apply(args);
  }

  console.log(ArgumentsToArray.apply(fnc));
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: WTH is `ArgumentsToArray` supposed to do? You don't have to deal with arrays anywhere? Just pass the resolver functions as arguments when calling `fnc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, named arguments do not exists in javascript, what we have is function arity ( with caveats ) with the `length` property and argument destructuring. So there is no way to test the "names of the arguments". For your test you could do :

```
const spy = ( resolve, reject ) => {
    expect(typeof resolve).toBe("function");
    expect(typeof resolve).toBe("function");

};
```

And pass this spy to your constructor.

This is an interesting endeavour but you should try and start from the spec. The `Promise` constructor introduced by the spec is there mostly for discoverability ( with the `constructor`property ).

Here are the spec : https://promisesaplus.com/, just try to understand and reimplement a simple `resolve`procedure for starter, the specs do have a test suite to help you ( distrubuted as a npm package ).